# How do I get older versions of Minecraft(1.13 and earlier) to function on my Mac without crashing?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am attempting to run Minecraft 1.8.9 on my Macbook. More recent versions of Minecraft (1.14+) function normally. It typically crashes several seconds after launching. I have attempted multiple things to fix it including reinstalling both Minecraft and Java, selecting the specific Java Executable, renaming Minecraft, scanning for malware, allocated more RAM to Minecraft. I have both Java and Minecraft fully updated. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you try installing the Adopt jdk rather then the Oracle one? https://adoptopenjdk.net/

Comment: @valkrie_pilot instead of basically just saying "save this" could you explain a bit why?

Comment: I have tried installing the Adopt JDK but there was no effect. Do I need to remove prior Oracle jdks?

Comment: Download and extract https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk8-binaries/releases/download/jdk8u282-b08/OpenJDK8U-jre_x64_mac_hotspot_8u282b08.tar.gz. Open launcher. Open Latest Release. Set Java executable to Where you extracted the file to -> bin -> java. If this doesn't work try using MultiMC (https://multimc.org). If either of these work, let me know and I'll add an answer.

Comment: Multimc functioned and allowed me to use older versions. Optifine still does not work as it requires the game to be opened in the initial launcher

Comment: You can use OptiFine with MultiMC: https://github.com/MultiMC/Launcher/wiki/MultiMC-and-OptiFine.